# How to use MATLAB fminunc for multiple arguments of optimization?

Tags: matlab

[image: Optimization]

Please refer to attached figure for the problem. In that figure variable q, g, and h are vector where as sigma is scalar quantity. I'm fine in handling single arguments for optimization problem using MATLAB fminunc whether its in scalar or vector.

But I'm not able to use for this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a question of rearranging the data so that all your optimization variables are in one array.

For example, consider the following super simple objective function

```
function obj_val = my_obj(q, g, h, sigma)
    obj_val = sigma*(q.'*q) + (h.'*h)*(g.'*g);
end
```

where we want to find the optimal `q` and `g` for some constant `h` and `sigma`. Then I could do the following

```
% constants
h = randn(6,1);
sigma = abs(randn());

% initial guess
q0 = randn(5,1);
g0 = randn(10,1);

% get dimensions of the variables
nq = numel(q0);
sq = size(q0);
ng = numel(g0);
sg = size(g0);

% Single variable containing both initial guesses
x0 = [q0(:); g0(:)];
% wrapper function which just takes x and distributes it to the arguments of my_obj
f = @(x) my_obj(reshape(x(1:nq), sq), reshape(x(nq+1:nq+ng), sg), h, sigma);

% solve for optimal x
x_opt = fminunc(f, x0);

% recover optimal q and g
q_opt = reshape(x_opt(1:nq), sq);
g_opt = reshape(x_opt(nq+1:nq+ng), sg);

fprintf('Resulting objective: %g\n', my_obj(q_opt, g_opt, h, sigma));
```

---

*Note:* Clearly the optimal point is (**q,g**) = (**0**,**0**) in this example.